# Transpose of vector problem

Tags: linear-algebra

So if I have a column vector $X = A\cos(\theta) + B\sin(\theta)$ where $A$ and $B$ are also both column vectors, how do I express $X^{\mathsf{T}}$ ($X$ transpose)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1\strut\\ a_2\\ \vdots\\ a_n\strut
\end{bmatrix},\qquad B=\begin{bmatrix}
b_1\strut\\ b_2\\ \vdots\\ b_n\strut
\end{bmatrix},$$
then for any scalars $c$ and $d$, we have
$$cA+dB=\begin{bmatrix}
ca_1\strut\\ ca_2\\ \vdots\\ ca_n\strut
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
db_1\strut\\ db_2\\ \vdots\\ db_n\strut
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
ca_1+db_1\strut\\ ca_2+db_2\\ \vdots\\ ca_n+db_n\strut
\end{bmatrix}$$
and therefore
$$(cA+dB)^{\mathsf{T}}=\begin{bmatrix}
ca_1+db_1\vphantom{\big|^a} & ca_2+db_2 & \cdots & ca_n+db_n
\end{bmatrix}.$$
But this is precisely equal to $cA^\mathsf{T}+dB^\mathsf{T}$.

In other words, it doesn't matter whether we add and multiply first, then rearrange how we wrote down the entries on our piece of paper, or rearrange them first and then add and multiply.